# Applying tags to instances created with for each Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, foreach

I have multiple EC2 instances created using for each. Each instance is being deployed into a different subnet. I am getting an error when trying to apply tags to each instance being deployed. Any advice would be helpful. Below is the code for my tags and instances:

```
resource "aws_instance" "private" {
  for_each      = aws_subnet.private
  ami           = var.ec2_amis[var.region]
  instance_type = var.tableau_instance
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.tableau.key_name
  subnet_id     = each.value.id

  tags = {
    Name = var.ec2_tags[each.key]
  }
}

variable "ec2_tags" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "PrimaryEC2",
    "EC2Worker1",
    "EC2Worker2"
  ]
}
```

**Error**

```
Error: Invalid index

  on vpc.tf line 21, in resource "aws_instance" "private":
  21:     Name = var.ec2_tags[each.key]
    |----------------
    | each.key is "3"
    | var.ec2_tags is list of string with 3 elements

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

I had this code working earlier, not sure what happened. I made a change to the AMI it spins up, but I don't see why that could have an effect on tags. Any advice would be helpful.

**UPDATE**
I have updated the resource with the following locals block and dynamic block within my "aws_instance" "private" code:

```
locals {
  private_instance = [{
    name = "PrimaryEC2"
    },
    {
      name = "EC2Worker1"
    },
    {
      name = "EC2Worker2"
  }]
}


    dynamic "tags" {
    for_each = local.private_instance

    content {
      Name = tags.value.name
    }
  }
```

**Error**

```
Error: Unsupported block type

  on vpc.tf line 28, in resource "aws_instance" "private":
  28:   dynamic "tags" {

Blocks of type "tags" are not expected here.
```

Any advice how to fix would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make your tags dynamic, you could create them as follows:

```
  tags = {
    Name = each.key == "0" ? "PrimaryEC2" : "EC2Worker${each.key}" 
  }
```

You would use it as follows (assuming everything else is OK):

```
resource "aws_instance" "private" {
  for_each      = aws_subnet.private
  ami           = var.ec2_amis[var.region]
  instance_type = var.tableau_instance
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.tableau.key_name
  subnet_id     = each.value.id

  tags = {
    Name = each.key == "0" ? "PrimaryEC2" : "EC2Worker${each.key}" 
  }
}
```

The code uses [conditional expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). It works as follows.

If each.key is equal to "0" (i.e., first instance being created) then its tag will be "PrimaryEC2". All remaining instances will be tagged: "EC2Worker1", "EC2Worker2", "EC2Worker3" and so on for as many subnets there are.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, if you can elaborate on this syntax it would be helpful. I am not quite sure I understand how you are specifying. I will update the question with the new code for my dynamic block and error.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this errors is that the `aws_subnet.private` variable is longer then the list of ec2 tags which would result in an error when the index 3 is used on your ec2_tags list looking for the 4th (nonexistent element).

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Maybe if I use a dynamice "tag" block, that may help. I'll try that.

Comment: As written you wind up with an instance per subnet, and potentially run out of name tags. Perhaps a map of name to subnet or iterating over names might yield desired behavior.